# How do I delete an <li> on click with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having trouble finding the right syntax to use to delete an element. I have a list item that I generate with a form that I want to also be deleted when I click on it. Here is my current javascript code:

```
// add to do items
let todoList = [];

function addTodo(item){
  todoList.push(item);
  //display item
}

const addButton = document.querySelector('.btn__display');
const formInput = document.querySelector('.addItem');
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const todoUl = document.querySelector('ul');
  const todoLi = document.createElement('li');
  todoLi.textContent = formInput.value;
  todoList.push(formInput.value);
  todoUl.appendChild(todoLi);
  formInput.value = '';
});
```

So far I can add an item to my todo list but how do I go about deleting it with a click?

Comment: Call `.remove()` on the element?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onclick listener to the newly created `li` element to remove it when clicked:

`todoLi.onclick = (e) => e.target.remove();`

```js
// add to do items
let todoList = [];

function addTodo(item) {
  todoList.push(item);
  //display item
}

const addButton = document.querySelector('.btn__display');
const formInput = document.querySelector('.addItem');
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const todoUl = document.querySelector('ul');
  const todoLi = document.createElement('li');
  todoLi.textContent = formInput.value;
  todoLi.onclick = (e) => e.target.remove();
  todoList.push(formInput.value);
  todoUl.appendChild(todoLi);
  formInput.value = '';
});
```

```html
<button class="btn__display">btn__display</button>
<input type="text" class="addItem">
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Luis's answer, you can do the following:

```
// add to do items
let todoList = [];

function addTodo(item){
  todoList.push(item);
  //display item
}

const addButton = document.querySelector('.btn__display');
const formInput = document.querySelector('.addItem');
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const todoUl = document.querySelector('ul');
  const todoLi = document.createElement('li');
  todoLi.textContent = formInput.value;
  todoList.push(formInput.value);
  todoUl.appendChild(todoLi);
  formInput.value = '';

  todoLi.addEventListener('click', function () {
      this.remove();
  });
});
```

The difference being that we are instead adding the event listener with a function where `this` will be set to the list item.

https://jsfiddle.net/gy9cLum3/

Comment: You could also, `todoLi.onclick = function() { this.remove() };` -- all are functions, I would go with the ES6 syntax.

Comment: I'm just using what the asker has already provided. He isn't using ES6 syntax so neither am I.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code:

```
<ul>
 <li onclick="remove(this)">lorem</li>
</ul>
<script>function remove(elem) { elem.parentElemet.removeChild(elem); } </script>
```